# Slow update queries (Select 20 times faster or bad table/query definition)?

Tags: mysql

I currently develop a module for prestashop and did some debuging. My update queries take 20 times longer even than multitable select queries.

Full debug looks like:

```
37.61 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'dpd', `cena` = 18.36 WHERE `package_id` = 304620 LIMIT 1
36.695 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 3, `kurier` = 'dpd', `cena` = 139.99 WHERE `package_id` = 303915 LIMIT 1
28.798 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 3, `kurier` = 'ups', `cena` = 20.34 WHERE `package_id` = 303914 LIMIT 1
25.523 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 3, `kurier` = 'kex', `cena` = 15.85 WHERE `package_id` = 303913 LIMIT 1
21.014 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'dpd', `cena` = 19.74 WHERE `package_id` = 290048 LIMIT 1
21.013 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'dpd', `cena` = 18.36 WHERE `package_id` = 289821 LIMIT 1
20.988 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'dpd', `cena` = 17.68 WHERE `package_id` = 290788 LIMIT 1
20.981 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'ups', `cena` = 19.74 WHERE `package_id` = 290790 LIMIT 1
20.944 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'kex', `cena` = 15.03 WHERE `package_id` = 289822 LIMIT 1
20.858 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 2, `kurier` = 'ups', `cena` = 19.74 WHERE `package_id` = 290242 LIMIT 1
19.805 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'ups', `cena` = 19.74 WHERE `package_id` = 290789 LIMIT 1
19.791 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 2, `kurier` = 'ups', `cena` = 20.34 WHERE `package_id` = 303912 LIMIT 1
19.759 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'dpd', `cena` = 17.68 WHERE `package_id` = 290339 LIMIT 1
19.656 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'dpd', `cena` = 18.36 WHERE `package_id` = 290791 LIMIT 1
19.654 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'dpd', `cena` = 18.36 WHERE `package_id` = 289820 LIMIT 1
19.597 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'dpd', `cena` = 19.74 WHERE `package_id` = 290241 LIMIT 1
19.54 ms UPDATE `ps_fur_orders` SET `id_order` = 1, `kurier` = 'ups', `cena` = 19.74 WHERE `package_id` = 289951 LIMIT 1
2.315 ms SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE c.`name`, cl.`id_lang`, IF(cl.`id_lang` IS NULL, c.`value`, cl.`value`) AS value, c.id_shop_group, c.id_shop FROM `ps_configuration` c LEFT JOIN `ps_configuration_lang` cl ON (c.id_configuration = cl.id_configuration)
1.574 ms SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE h.`name` as hook, m.`id_module`, h.`id_hook`, m.`name` as module, h.`live_edit` FROM `ps_module` m INNER JOIN `ps_hook_module` hm ON hm.`id_module` = m.`id_module` INNER JOIN `ps_hook` h ON hm.`id_hook` = h.`id_hook` WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ps_module_shop ms WHERE ms.id_module = m.id_module AND ms.id_shop IN (1)) = 1) AND (h.name != "displayPayment") AND (hm.id_shop = 1) ORDER BY hm.`position`
-- [rest is lower than 0.6ms, that's why I wrote 20 times :) ]
```

Table has 17 entries and Unique key set on `package_id`.
Table definition looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_fur_orders` (
    `id_order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `package_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `package_no` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `kurier` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cena` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE KEY `package_id` (`package_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

An `UPDATE` requires committing data to disk, which is likely where your time is coming from. On an untuned or low performance machine, 20ms to commit is not unheard of at all.

Comment: But why it lowers every query? Every page refresh its same. It goes from like around 40ms to 18ms at lowest.
It's Xampp on windows machine. Database is slow overall, but difference is astounding by me. Especially that table has only 17 entries, and multi table join is faster than that.

Comment: You're probably reading too much into the times and your sample set is too small. Could be many things, but my best guess is some of the data was in cache and some wasn't...